# Removing An Anchor Tag Using PHP (currently using strip_tags)

Tags: php

I'm pulling some text in from the backend, and now I'm trying to remove an anchor tag that's coming with it. I'm using `strip_tags`, but can't figure out why it isn't working.

Also: I'm okay with alternatives if this isn't the best approach

**What I've Tried:**

```
<?php 
    $downloadcategory = the_terms( $post->ID, 'download_category', '' );
    $downloadcategory .= strip_tags($downloadcategory);

    echo $downloadcategory;
?>
```

and

```
<?php 
    $downloadcategory = the_terms( $post->ID, 'download_category', '' );

    echo strip_tags($downloadcategory);
?>
```

Comment: do you want to remove just the anchor tag or all html tags

Comment: I just want the anchor gone, but it's the only tag present so either will work!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 
    $downloadcategory = the_terms( $post->ID, 'download_category', '' );
    echo filter_var($downloadcategory ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. At first it printed "downloadcategory", but then I changed it to "$downloadcategory" and it printed like before with the anchor tag wrapping the category name

Comment: can you show me a sample of your data including the tag

Comment: that's weird! in my case it is stripping all html tag. I use exactly the same data as in the image and it just print the text inside the anchor tag